# jCart error with PHP 5.3.8

Tags: php, shopping-cart

When I use the [jCart](http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/) library  on **PHP 5.3.8**, I found the error like this

```
Notice: Undefined index: jcart in D:\Website\JCART\jcart\jcart.php on line 588

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 80

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 166

Notice: Undefined variable: config in D:\Website\JCART\jcart\config-loader.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: text in D:\Website\JCART\jcart\config-loader.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: singleItem in D:\Website\JCART\jcart\config-loader.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: multipleItems in D:\Website\JCART\jcart\config-loader.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: subtotal in D:\Website\JCART\jcart\config-loader.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: update in D:\Website\JCART\jcart\config-loader.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined index: checkout in D:\Website\JCART\jcart\config-loader.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: checkoutPaypal in D:\Website\JCART\jcart\config-loader.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: removeLink in D:\Website\JCART\jcart\config-loader.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: emptyButton in D:\Website\JCART\jcart\config-loader.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined index: emptyMessage in D:\Website\JCART\jcart\config-loader.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined index: itemAdded in D:\Website\JCART\jcart\config-loader.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined index: priceError in D:\Website\JCART\jcart\config-loader.php on line 25

Notice: Undefined index: quantityError in D:\Website\JCART\jcart\config-loader.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined index: checkoutError in D:\Website\JCART\jcart\config-loader.php on line 27

Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in D:\Website\JCART\index.php on line 4
```

I have tried the solutions in this forum : [jCart Forum](http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/help/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2964)

But I have not found a solution to this problem. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL &~ (E_DEPRECATED | E_NOTICE))` It doesn't fix it but it will hide that mess. I recommend you find a better cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tos are basic php variable settings - put an @ sign infront of all $config variables and they should vanish - or replace with an isset but an @ sign is easier: ie

```
if(!$config... 

change to:

if(!@$config...
```

can also change

```
$config to @$config - use the error msgs to locate file and line number ;)
```

btw this doesnt work on xampp - but fine on wamp and linux for some odd reason